# Selenium WebDriver is not able to connect to Firefox

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am unable to launch Firefox browser(53) using selenium webdriver (3.11)
The code works well with Chromedriver but gives exception with Firefox.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class CNN {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.cnn.com");
        String text =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='intl_homepage1-zone-1']/div[2]/div/div[1]/ul/li[1]/article/a/h2")).getText();
        System.out.println(text);
    }


}
```

This is the exception that i am getting:-

```
 Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:5542
    Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:33:08.638Z'
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you download and install gecko driver for Firefox? 
If not please do it and use as system properties while running test in Firefox.

Comment: It worked! not only for this class but also the other classes where firefox was not working. Thanks

Comment: You need to create CapabilitiesGenerator for the current version of WebDriver and read more about WebDriverFactory Pattern.

Comment: how to create capabilitesgenerator, where can i find webdriverfactory pattern information